# Adding new address to BroadcastGroup in Akka

Tags: java, akka, actor

In one of my actor I'm creating a router-actor child like this:

```
this.actorRouter = getContext().actorOf(Props.empty().withRouter(new BroadcastGroup(neighbours)), "router");
```

Where `neighbours` is list of strings (address). Now I want to be able to change that list. For example, when a new message arrives from an unknown actor and I want to add his address to my router. I tried to just execute the above line with the new list, however, that results in an error:

> Actor name is already taken

Is it possible to manipulate a BroadcastGroup once it is created?

Answer (score 1):

from [the doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#Management_Messages)

Management Messages

- Sending akka.routing.GetRoutees to a router actor will make it send
  back its currently used routees in a akka.routing.Routees message.
- Sending akka.routing.AddRoutee to a router actor will add that routee to its collection of routees.
- Sending akka.routing.RemoveRoutee to a router actor will remove that routee to its collection of routees.
- Sending akka.routing.AdjustPoolSize to a pool router actor will add or remove that number of routees to its collection of routees.